# Color on tree using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I want to highlight a certain path on a probability tree that I draw using tikz and forest ([thanks to this source](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/probability-tree/)):

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{forest,nicefrac}
    \begin{document}
    % Set the overall layout of the tree
    \tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=3.5cm, sibling distance=3.5cm]
    \tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=3.5cm, sibling distance=2cm]
    % Define styles for bags and leafs
    \tikzstyle{bag} = [text width=4em, text centered]
    \tikzstyle{end} = [circle, minimum width=3pt,fill, inner sep=0pt]
    % The sloped option gives rotated edge labels. Personally
    % I find sloped labels a bit difficult to read. Remove the sloped options
    % to get horizontal labels. 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, sloped]
\node[bag] {}
    child {
        node[bag] {II $(2R,1B)$}        
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$P(B\cap II)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$B$}
                node[below]  {$\frac{1}{3}$}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$P(R\cap II)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$R$}
                node[below]  {$\frac{2}{3}$}
            }
            edge from parent 
            node[above] {$II$}
            node[below]  {$\frac{1}{2}$}
    }
    child {
        node[bag] {I $(2R,4B)$}        
        child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$P(B\cap I)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{4}{6}$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$B$}
                node[below]  {$\frac{4}{6}$}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$P(R\cap I)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{6}$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$R$}
                node[below]  {$\frac{2}{6}$}
            }
        edge from parent         
            node[above] {$I$}
            node[below]  {$\frac{1}{2}$}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

How can I highlight the path I,R? It can be highlight just by making the edges ticker or a different color or change the background color, whatever you think it is better practice.

Comment: I've removed the `forest` tag, because you're not actually using a `forest` tree. I would recommend using `forest`, though, it far surpasses the standard `tikz` tree methods . There are lots of similar trees done in `forest` that you can find on the site.

Comment: I am going to take a look at forest options, @AlanMunn. Thank you!

Comment: @AlanMunn I'm pretty sure there is Forest code for a tree somewhere on the site pretty much just like this one, too. It looks very familiar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like this?

[image]

for this you need only  add option `[draw=red,ultra thick]` to `child` :

```
         child[draw=red,ultra thick] { % <-- added option for emphasize line R
            node[end, label=right:
                {$P(R\cap I)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{6}$}] {}
            edge from parent
            node[above] {$R$}
            node[below]  {$\frac{2}{6}$}
            }
```

Comment: That is great, @Zarko. Thank you very much! I have so much to learn from Tikz!